# is "->" in php similar (a.k.a equivalent) to "." in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

In other words, php

```
$object->method();
```

and

```
$object->property = 'someValue';
```

---

is equivalent to, js:

```
$object.method();
```

and

```
$object.property = 'someValue';
```

I am curious, or is my php and js understanding messed up?

Comment: It's similar, yes. But JS doesn't have classes like PHP does.

Comment: NB: `->` is called the "arrow operator", and `o.p` is called "dot notation" (as opposed to "bracket notation": `o[s]`, where `s=='p'`). I don't believe there's an official name for `.` in JS, though you could call it the "dot operator" and be understood. Using `->`, `.` or `[]` (in their appropriate languages) is called "property access" or "member access" (the former term in PHP is usually restricted to refer to accessing object fields, rather than methods).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar, and yet so different.

One *big* -- but not exclusive! -- difference is that, in PHP, methods are *bound* to an instance of a class, while in JavaScript, methods are just functions (which are *first-class-values*) that happen to be named by ("stored in") properties of objects.

Since PHP methods are *bound* to an instance of a class, this means that `$this` inside does not change depending on how the method was invoked.

In JavaScript, however, `object.member(...)` is equivalent to `object["member"].call(object, ...)`: the `this` inside the JavaScript method is *entirely* dependent upon how the function is invoked. (This is why callbacks in JavaScript sometimes require closures to pass `this` through correctly.)

As you continue to learn/use both languages (and hopefully different languages entirely!), you will be able to see more similarities and differences in both fundamental design differences and syntax. Learning to "respect" a language, for what it is and how it does things, is a good way to be friends with it.

Happy coding.

Comment: It's been a while since I last read your answer, but I am glad I did  it again. Looking back some time later at it, it is really something. Back then, I was just looking for the right answer. But now I see your last paragraph as quite inspirational. I do not know who you are, but you just inspired someone (me).

Comment: @user744184 That makes me smile to read, and, as always, happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much it is, both allow you to access properties and methods on objects.

Remember that JavaScript has a quite different object system which is class-less out of the box.

Comment: …and forever more thereafter. Amen.

Answer (score 1):

**Your question is "are they *similar*" – the answer is "yes."**

The nuances of prototypal or classical inheritance are interesting, sure, but for your purposes (especially if you're at the point of asking this question) you should proceed as if they're equivalent. Enjoy the world of Javascript, its a ton of fun. When you're ready to ask more questions, read a [comparison with class-based models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming#Comparison_with_class-based_models) and enjoy the nuances!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, PHP is Server Side whereas Javascript is Client Side.
So decide which side you want your methods or variable should work?

Come to your core Question :
"   is “->” in php similar to “.” in javascript?   "

The answer is No. Because in PHP, You Have to make an Object of a class first & then You can use that object. Whereas in JS(JavaScript) there is no need of Class.

Use of both PHP and JS in appropriate manner can help u a lot to make a nice site...

Comment: Not a helpful answer. The question is about semantics, not where the programming should be used (server or client side). Furthermore, JavaScript can be used server side (see Node.js for example). Finally, I believe that the two notations the OP mentions are in fact quite similar, as per pst's answer.